# git pull isn't overwriting local files on second pull

Tags: git, github, netbeans

Using NetBeans 8.1 on macOS Mojave for a PHP project which is hosted on a private GitHub repo. Let's say it's called `foo-repo`.

I've configured my Project Properties in NetBeans so it can Push and Pull from `foo-repo`. It's connecting fine and no errors are reported.

There are 3 branches on the repo: `master`, `devA`, `devB`. I'm working in the `devA` branch locally.

When I initially start NetBeans and want to update my local files to the `master` branch I right-click on the project and go to Git > Remote > Pull. If I check `master -> origin/master` it says:

> Branch `origin/master` will be merged into the current branch `devA`.

So far so good. This seems to work.

However, if I edit and save files locally **but do not commit or push them** I'm having problems. There are occasions where I want to "reset" my local files back to what's present on `master`. In this case I go through the above process again. NetBeans seems to connect to the repo without reporting errors. But none of my local files, which I've edited/saved, show the content of the `master` branch. Instead they show the edits I made, which I no longer want.

As an example, say I launch NetBeans and do the initial Pull. I have a file `foo.php` which contains this:

```
$foo = 'bar';
```

Let's say I edit it as follows:

```
$foo = 'xyz';
$newVar = 123;
```

I save this file locally in NetBeans **but do not commit or push it to the GitHub repo**.

I close all of my open files.

When I then do Git > Remote > Pull and check `master -> origin/master` it still says:

> Branch `origin/master` will be merged into the current branch `devA`.

There is a message in the bottom taskbar saying it's pulling from `foo-repo`.

But when I re-open `foo.php` I see this:

```
$foo = 'xyz';
$newVar = 123;
```

That isn't what's on `master`.

Is this a bug/issue with NetBeans? Or is this the wrong process to get back to the `master` branch state using git?

Edit - Someone has answered saying

> *You don't commit the modified file... so the file is modified and no revision is built on it.... then you run pull. The pull runs fine because there are no changes coming from master that are modifying the file. If there were a change on master touching the file, git will cough on it and will warn you that the operation will overwrite your changes and to stash your changes or commit them.*

Why would I commit a file containing work which I **don't** want in the repo? If one of the purposes of using git is to get files into a known state, the state I want is what's on `master` and the branch I want the contents in exists (`devA`). Can git not cope with this?

Similarly the suggestion of using `git checkout foo.php` is fine if you've only changed `foo.php`. What if you've changed multiple files, closed them, and can't remember the filenames? This all seems counterintuitive.

Comment: I believe it's `git checkout foo.php` what you are looking for.

Comment: That's ok if you're trying to revert 1 file. What if you've edited 100 files? And potentially closed some of them in the IDE so can't remember their names?

Comment: `git checkout .` will revert all modified files.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding in what *pull* actually means. Pull won't overwrite the files you have modified. It will (normally) merge content... you wanting the files back to how they were on master is a different operation from what pull or merge do.

There's an additional catch for what you describe. You don't commit the modified file... so the file is modified and no revision is built on it.... then you run pull. The pull runs fine because there are no changes coming from master that are modifying the file. If there were a change on master touching the file, git will cough on it and will warn you that the operation will overwrite your changes and to stash your changes or commit them.

Comment: So how can I achieve what I'm looking to do? Surely that's possible with git since that's one of the reasons for using it, i.e. reverting contents of files to a known state. In this case the state I want is what's on `master`

Comment: If you would like to get the file back to what it was in the revision you are on (aka **HEAD**), you can do `git checkout -- the-file.txt`. This will require no revision. If you want to get the file back to how it was on some other place _with content different from what is on `HEAD`_, you can use `git checkout some-branch -- the-file.txt` _and_ it will require a revision for the change to be a change that makes it into the history of your branch..